# Intuition behind combinatorics formula of $2^n -1$

Tags: combinatorics

I recently got introduced to the combinatorics formula of $2^n -1$, the teacher said this is to be applied whenever we want the sum of a whole series of combinations from r=1 to r=n, and I understood this, but than she directly applied this formula to the following problem : "A man has 5 German, 4 Spanish and 3 French friends, what are the total ways of invitation so that there is at least 1 German friend.", she applied the (2 raise to n) - 1 formula and got the answer as
$$
 (2^5-1)\cdot 2^7
$$
. I didn't understand how we could apply the formula here, could somebody help?

Comment: The number of way of inviting people, so that there is at least one German, is the same as inviting at least one German, and then choosing some amount (0 or more) of the seven remaining people. We can start by looking at the Germans. The way of choosing "at least 1" of them, is equal to "choosing any number" minus 1 (because we discard "choose none"). Therefore, this gets the value $2^5-1$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of the idiom "to gas friends"? I have not found anything appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

- There are $2^5$ subsets of the set of German friends, but we are asekd no ignore the empty set; so $2^5-1$
- There are $2^7$ subsets of the set of Spanish/French friends; so $2^7$
- To combine, multiply.